# Killing a Perl process in Linux

Tags: linux, process, perl, daemon

I started a perl process that runs a script and I want to end it, but not the rest of perl scripts. How do I target it and not the rest?

Comment: Seriously ? It was easier to write this than to look it up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `kill` it by its process id (PID), like any other linux process:

```
$ kill 12345
```

If you don't know the PID, you can figure it out with `ps`:

```
$ ps -ef | grep myperlscript
user  3936  3904  0 Feb02 ?        01:13:31 /usr/bin/perl ...
```

The PID is the second value in each line of output, `3936` in this example.